# 'Export' HEAD from remote Subversion repository and commit it to a Local repository

Tags: svn, repository

We have a remote (hosted elsewhere) Subversion repository that has a variety of commits in it. Every time a milestone release is done, we want to get a copy of that release and commit it to a locally hosted SVN Repository.

Right now, I am doing it this way:

I have a local working copy of our internal SVN repository, and a folder that has an exported copy of the remote repository. When a release is complete, I export a fresh copy to the folder with the exports, and then copy it (overwrite) it to my local working copy of our internal SVN repository.

I then commit the working copy to our internal repository.

**Is there an easier/simpler way of accomplishing this?**

- It has to be subversion, we cannot use Git or another SCM
- We do not need multiple HEAD's

I appreciate/welcome any and all ideas.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you need to do this? When you export from the remote repo I assume you lose all of the associated commit history, so I can't imagine you're doing this for redundancy purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Because you always know URL of "milestone release", you can use this URL as definition of svn:externals inside your repository (i.e some **permanent URL** in *your* repository, unrelated to ordinary development, will contain changeable content from changeable remote-URL).

On new milestone you'll have only change externals definition and commit it